# Digitalocean hosted node app 502 Bad Gateway for POST/GET

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have node app hosted on digitalocean.

In file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default I have written

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name dailymartbasket.in;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

## Problem:

When I call my domain name in browser then angular app inside this node app gets loaded which is at / route. from angular app we are making some POST/GET calls to node app but it returns error for those routes

`Request URL:http://<domainname>/api/categories
Request Method:GET
Status Code:502 Bad Gateway
Remote Address:<droplet ip>:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Please suggest what is wrong, I am pretty new to server hosting

Comment: A 502 response should be accompanied by either your Node app, or NGINX, logging something that would provide a clue.

Comment: @robertklep I am new to server hosting can you tell me which logs you want exactly and how to get those?

Comment: The NGINX error file _might_ be stored in `/var/log/nginx`, but it entirely depends on both your OS and your NGINX setup. If there are any Node.js logfiles (or stored console output) also depends on your setup, there's no general location for those.

Comment: I get below error 
2017/07/09 09:52:04 [error] 5666#5666: *63 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: <droplet ip>, server: <domain name>, request: "GET /api/categories HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/categories", host: "45.55.177.57", referrer: "http://45.55.177.57/home"

Comment: That sounds like your Node app is crashing. Why, I can't say.

Comment: Thanks, resolved this issue, issue was with authentication was failing to mongo.